# Why wasn’t Eggsy affected by the crazy waves that Valentine sent out?

Tags: plot-explanation, kingsman-the-secret-service

When Valentine activated the thing that made everyone start killing each other and go all homicidal in *Kingsman: The Secret Service*, why wasn’t Eggsy affected at all? I never saw him be implanted with a chip and they never said that the bunker offered any type of protection. So why was he able to think clearly and not go crazy?

Comment: Similarly Valentine also didn't have a chip in the neck and he was calm and Gazelle too didn't go crazy. I think it was about the facility that people inside would not be affected.

Answer (score 3):

The 'crazy waves' are transmitted by mobile phones that have Valentine's SIM card in them, which he distributes under the guise of offering a free service.  I presume the (audio?) signal they transmit has a relatively short range, but a lot of the world's population will be within a short distance of one or more phones.

I presume that Eggsy and Merlin, being aware of the plot, don't carry such phones.  Also I imagine that the entire of Valentine's mountain hideout doesn't contain any such enabled phones or possibly have cellphone service at that location deep within a remote mountain.  They make a big deal over having to get the WiFi password to get access to the internet, probably because there's no service at that location.

Comment: I also think that the implanted chips weren't relevant to the "crazy waves", either.  They were relevant to Valentine's ability to control the VIPs recruited into the plan.  IOW, the "deal" was "I include you in the group that survives and is protected from what's coming, and in exchange I get to blow your head off if you break our agreement."

Comment: That may be true, I think they were also told that it protected them.  I seem to recall not all people are planning to go to Valentine's hideout to last out the event.

Comment: Valentine also ran a test in a small church and it didn't appear that anyone outside of the church was impacted.